# WP7 , High CPU Utilization

Tags: performance, windows-phone-7, cpu

I am building a WP7 application.
I noticed high cpu utilization using the Performance Monitoring tool.

Even a simple hello world application gives High CPU utilization.
This happens in the UI Thread.

How do we get the application to use less then 50 % of the CPU ?

[image]

This image is that of the hello world application. We can see the the graph is easily above 50%.
Is that an area of concern ?

Answer (score 1):

In isolation a single measurement of an application starting up and taking, for a short while, more than 50% of CPU time is not a matter of concern.

One way to make the application use less (as a percentage) of the CPU time is to make sure that, when you start it, the CPU is already working flat out (ie 100%) on other tasks.  The o/s should then make sure that your starting application gets only a smaller share of CPU time.

And if that previous paragraph makes you shout 'that's not what I meant !' well, I only offer it as an example of how a single measurement of CPU time (or most other performance measures for that matter) is almost useless as the basis for an argument for refactoring or any other corrective action.

Comment: By default, in WP7 developement environment when i run the profiling tool and use a device, is the graph a measure of the consolidated CPU usage or is it the individual CPU usage by the application in question?

Comment: There's another reason for not giving any weight to the measurement, you don't know what it's measuring !  In this case nor do I.